# Autodesk PDF Extension - Preventing page in query string override

Tags: pdf, autodesk-forge

I'm currently looking to implement pagination within the ForgeViewer PDF Extenstion, in the documentation there's a note that 'page' in the querystring will override any value passed to load model. I wondered if this was configurable or we were able to prevent this.

```
// URL parameter page will override value passed to loadModel 

viewer.loadModel(‘path/to/file.pdf’, { page: 1 });
```

This is causing us a few issues as we use 'page' for other purposes and we'll have to rework quite a bit to rename our current page querystring which we're using for paginating tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. If you look inside the **PDF extension**'s code (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/PDF/PDF.js) then you'll find that this behaviour is hardcoded unfortunately 
[image]

I can think of two workarounds: 
a) Use a URL param other than `page` - e.g. `sheet`?

b) Overwrite the current URL so that the page number will become what you need

```
// Original URL is: http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html?page=2
// we change it to page=1
// This should change the URL content without a reload
history.pushState('', '', 'index.html?page=1');
viewer.loadModel("AutoCAD_Sample_Part1.pdf", {}, (model) => {
```

You could also achieve the same like this:

```
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.PDF').then(function(ext) {
  // Original URL is: http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html?page=2
  // we change it to page=1
  viewer.loadModel("AutoCAD_Sample_Part1.pdf", {}, (model) => {
    ext.hyperlinkTracker.changePage(1)
```

Comment: Thanks Adam for your quick response. We were about to implement changes to change our queryParam as your first suggestion, thought it was worth popping up a question to see if we could get away with not.

I might have a go at hijacking the querystring as per your 2nd suggestion first.

Thanks very much!